# PHP Mailer: get_oauth_token.php returning empty refresh token on server but works fine on localhost

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, phpmailer

I need to send emails from contact forms using Gmail SMTP through a GSuite account. I tested everything on local machine and everything worked. But after deployment I can't generate the refresh token correctly. Here is the code I am running on the server.

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer - PHP email creation and transport class.
 * PHP Version 5.5
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 * @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2017 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */
/**
 * Get an OAuth2 token from an OAuth2 provider.
 * * Install this script on your server so that it's accessible
 * as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
 * e.g.: http://localhost/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php
 * * Ensure dependencies are installed with 'composer install'
 * * Set up an app in your Google/Yahoo/Microsoft account
 * * Set the script address as the app's redirect URL
 * If no refresh token is obtained when running this file,
 * revoke access to your app and run the script again.
 */

namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

/**
 * Aliases for League Provider Classes
 * Make sure you have added these to your composer.json and run `composer install`
 * Plenty to choose from here:
 * @see http://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/providers/thirdparty/
 */
// @see https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-google
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
// @see https://packagist.org/packages/hayageek/oauth2-yahoo
use Hayageek\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Yahoo;
// @see https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft
use Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft;

if (!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_GET['provider'])) {
?>
<html>
<body>Select Provider:<br/>
<a href='?provider=Google'>Google</a><br/>
<a href='?provider=Yahoo'>Yahoo</a><br/>
<a href='?provider=Microsoft'>Microsoft/Outlook/Hotmail/Live/Office365</a><br/>
</body>
</html>
<?php
exit;
}

require '/home4/findynoy/public_html/i3minds.co.in/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$providerName = '';

if (array_key_exists('provider', $_GET)) {
    $providerName = $_GET['provider'];
    $_SESSION['provider'] = $providerName;
} elseif (array_key_exists('provider', $_SESSION)) {
    $providerName = $_SESSION['provider'];
}
if (!in_array($providerName, ['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Yahoo'])) {
    exit('Only Google, Microsoft and Yahoo OAuth2 providers are currently supported in this script.');
}

//These details are obtained by setting up an app in the Google developer console,
//or whichever provider you're using.
$clientId = '637142774117-v1j200em1eh9ug52nmhf9u2mh5cblp63.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'VI2CxFxlBLD0lGaJd9b4OX61';

//If this automatic URL doesn't work, set it yourself manually to the URL of this script
// $redirectUri = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$redirectUri = 'https://i3minds.co.in/get_oauth_token.php';

$params = [
    'clientId' => $clientId,
    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    'redirectUri' => $redirectUri,
    'accessType' => 'offline'
];

$options = [];
$provider = null;

switch ($providerName) {
    case 'Google':
        $provider = new Google($params);
        $options = [
            'scope' => [
                'https://mail.google.com/'
            ]
        ];
        break;
    case 'Yahoo':
        $provider = new Yahoo($params);
        break;
    case 'Microsoft':
        $provider = new Microsoft($params);
        $options = [
            'scope' => [
                'wl.imap',
                'wl.offline_access'
            ]
        ];
        break;
}

if (null === $provider) {
    exit('Provider missing');
}

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    unset($_SESSION['provider']);
    exit('Invalid state');
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['provider']);
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        [
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        ]
    );
    // Use this to interact with an API on the users behalf
    // Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
    echo 'Refresh Token: ', $token->getRefreshToken();
}
```

[image: This is the output from the server]

This is what I receive from the server. I assume refresh token can't be empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider removing all personal credentials from your post.  As the edit queue is full, it's not possible for me to redact them.   Consider your current set of credentials as no longer valid and generate a new set.

Comment: @ewong These are outdated credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you solved case, but from documentation, google return refresh token first time only, later if it's not changed, it's not returned.

You need to save it.